# Transaction PDF layout not printing line level data

Tags: netsuite

[image]NetSuite: I am trying to modify the Transaction PDF layout for picking tickets as advanced PDF do not work for this. However, I am struggling to add anything to the template as the newly added fields only show the labels and no data at the line level. Any idea what needs to be done to add fields with value please?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is very difficult with the old style template shown in your screen shot. You will have much better success using the Advanced HTML/PDF templates